# Problem with Windows 10 Chinese Input

Tags: pinyin, word

Disclaimer: I started to learn chinese a few weeks ago..

I just installed the Chinese Simplified input method on my Windows 10 laptop and started doing some tests with pinyin and Microsoft Word. However, something seems to be wrong or (more likely) I am missing something:

when I try to type "girl" in pinyin I got the wrong characters completed. That is, I enter `nuhai` I got this: 奴孩  is this the correct character for girl?

Comment: Accurately, The pinyin of "女" is "nü", and generally use "v" to stand for it. So just type "nv"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Chinese , you should press **"nv"** instead of "nu". "v" here means "ü" in pronunciation.

For more about Pinyin, you can see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinyin

Comment: Can you point me to a guide for this? I mean, for the appropriate way to input pinyin in word?

Comment: @JohnTortugo：Only the ü should be pressed as "v". The others are the same as what you can see on our keyboards. You can download 搜狗拼音 at http://pinyin.sogou.com/index.php，This is better than the original one at Windows.

Answer (score -1):

> nv hai

or

> guniang (姑娘)

It  is girl  in Chinese language